# Is `git rebase` sensitive to your current branch?

Tags: git

Assume the following history exists and the current branch is "topic":

```
                 A---B---C topic
                /
           D---E---F---G master
```

Then if we issue the following commands:

1. `git rebase master`
2. `git rebase master topic`

Does it matter whether we are in the branch "topic" or "master"? That is, is it true that in either instance the outcome is as follows:

```
                         A'--B'--C' topic
                        /
           D---E---F---G master
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the same.

```
git rebase master topic
```

is a short-hand for

```
git checkout topic
git rebase master
```

Straight the [git-rebase documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> Assume the following history exists and the current branch is "topic":
>
> ```
>      A---B---C topic
>      /
> D---E---F---G master
> ```
>
> From this point, the result of either of the following commands:
>
> ```
> git rebase master
> git rebase master topic
> ```
>
> would be:
>
> ```
>              A'--B'--C' topic
>              /
> D---E---F---G master
> ```
>
> NOTE: The latter form is just a short-hand of `git checkout topic` followed by `git rebase master`. When rebase exits topic will remain the checked-out branch.

Answer (score 0):

> Is `git rebase` sensitive to your current branch?

well ...

> Assume the following history exists and the current branch is "topic":

The documentation specifically mentions the *current branch*, so: yes.

> Does it matter whether we are in the branch "topic" or "master"?

It matters if you *don't specify the branch to rebase on the command line*. The doc you pasted gives two versions, and the first doesn't specify the branch to rebase: hence, it defaults to the current branch.